# Maximizing Pearson Correlation, what should be loss function

Tags: python, statistics, deep-learning, keras, correlation

I'm using Keras for a deep learning prediction task and my aim is to maximize Pearson correlation between predicted values and true labels.

What would be the ideal loss function to use in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want a loss that minimizes the distance between the prediction distribution and the target distribution. So, the answer to this question depends on the distribution of your labels.

Assuming your labels are gaussian, MSE should be a good loss to go with. You can read more about MSE vs Pearson Correlation in this [stack exchange thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301659/mse-as-a-proxy-to-pearsons-correlation-in-regression-problems).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

def negative_correlaction(
    y_true,
    y_pred
):
    return -tf.math.reduce_mean(
        tfp.stats.correlation(
            y_true,
            y_pred,
            sample_axis=1, 
            event_axis=None
        )
    )

X = tf.random.normal((10, 10))
neg_corr = negative_correlaction(
    y_true = X[:2, :],
    y_pred = X[:2, :],
)
print(neg_corr)
```